# Error al consumir WS SOAP con Nusoap PHP

Tags: php, webservice, soap, php8, nusoap

Estoy aprendiendo a consumir WebServices de tipo SOAP, utilizando la librería Nusoap.
Este es mi codigo

```
<?php
//se incluye la librería
require_once('lib/nusoap.php');

//  Creamos la instancia como cliente
$urlWebService = 'https://www.phpcentral.com/ejemplos/webservice_nusoap01/server.php?wsdl';
$clienteSOAP = new nusoap_client($urlWebService, 'wsdl');

// Chekeamos para un posible error
$err = $clienteSOAP->getError();
if ($err) {
    echo 'Error en Constructor ' . $err;
}

// invocación del método del webservice
$respuesta = $clienteSOAP->call('saludar', array('nombre' => 'Fernando Mosquera'));

// Chekeamos para una falla al momento de llamar al metodo
if ($clienteSOAP->fault) {
    echo 'Fallo ';
    print_r($respuesta);
} else {    // Chequea errores
    $err = $clienteSOAP->getError();
    if ($err) {        // Muestra el error
        echo 'Error ' . $err;
    } else {        // Muestra el resultado
        echo 'Resultado ';
        print_r($respuesta);
    }
}
```

Pero el muestra el siguiente error

```
Error no transport found, or selected transport is not yet supported!
```

No se a que se debe, he investigado y no he podido encontrar una solución, al parecer es relacionado con el constructor pero no se mucho.
Le agradezco si alguien me pueda orientar

Comment: Hay una sección de preguntas en www.phpcentral.com y creo que ese sería el lugar adecuado para tratar de aclarar tu duda.

Answer (score 0):

Se que es vieja esta publicacion, pero hace unos dias se me presento este mismo problema; y no encontre ninguna solucion publicada asi que investigue al respecto y lo solucione agregando la siguiente linea debajo del llamado al WebService

```
$clienteSOAP = new nusoap_client($urlWebService, 'wsdl');
$client->setEndpoint('http://.....Endpoint');
```

La ruta del Endpoint tiene que venir en el WebService al final, en mi caso venian varias referencias y una de ellas indicaba location="", sin ninguna ruta. Asi que copie una de las otras referencias.

Otra solucion puede ser la version del nusoap.